# How to make higher than "public_html" folder work for cpanel installation?

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I currently have a basic cpanel hosting account. It has the setup:

```
/home/mysite/ --> my home directory
/home/mysite/www --> symlink to the next folder
/home/mysite/public_html --> where all my files live
```

Problem is, with the latest laravel installation I did, I have a website with structure:

```
/app/ --> appy stuff
/public/ ---> what needs to be exposed
```

My problem is, I dont want to chuck everything into /home/mysite as there are other folders in there too. Is there a way that I can make the html directory something like:

```
/home/mysite/public_html/public
```

This way if people open www.mysite.com, it hits the /public folder. And not the /public_html folder. Is there a way to do this on a basic cpanel hosting solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isnt the exact answer you want - but this is how I do it.

You rename `public` to `public_html` and there is no need to change any server settings.

Then in your bootstrap/paths.php file change

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
```

to

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public_html',
```

Then just put the other folders where they need to be.  Trying to muck around with cPanel settings, and leaving your Laravel app inside the public_html folder might lead to an issue down the track.